# How to write a regular expression in Java to match a text at the beginning followed by a special character?

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a program in java to check if a string starts with a specific text followed by a "|"

E.g

```
String a ="pro";
String b ="pro|100";
String c ="pro|loc";
String d ="pro|book|I'd";

String text ="pro";

String reg ="^"+text+[|]*; //this does not seem to work
```

The regex should match all `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` above

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be looking for something like

```
String reg ="^" + Pattern.quote(text) +"($|[|].*)";
```

you can remove `.*` if you want to use `Matcher#find` or leave it in case of `Matcher#matches`.

`Pattern.quote` generates regex which *represents literal* passed as argument. For instance if your `text` would be `"a+b"` it would return regex *equivalent* to `"a\\+b"`.